# Function not outputting correct value when checking if an array includes an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

What mistake have I made?

```
let array1= [
  {no: 1, names: "beef", from: "cow", price: 5},
  {no: 2, names: "pork", from: "pig", price: 10},
];

function printByNames(a) {
  if (array1.includes(a) == false) {
    return (a + " is not a meat!");
  } else {
    return array1.filter(function (object) {
        return console.log(object.names == a);
    })[0];
  }
}

//test in console = false when should return object.
printByNames("beef")
```

If the name is in the array, the function should console.log the whole object. If not, it should return the input + the string " is not a meat".

Comment: array1 does not include an entry `"beef"`, instead it has an entry with a `names`-property which is `"beef"`. So calling `array1.includes("beef")` will always yield false. (If you need more help, I'd be glad to write a full answer.)

Comment: Thank you! That logic helps me understand more. Don't worry about writing an awnser out. I got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the object like this

```
let array1= [
    {no: 1, names: "beef", from: "cow", price: 5},
    {no: 2, names: "pork", from: "pig", price: 10},
  ];

  function printByNames(a) {
    var arrayobject =  array1.find(function (object) {
          return object.names == a;
      });

      return arrayobject ? arrayobject : 'a is not a meat!'
  }
  printByNames("beef")
```

Comment: this is brilliant. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Kumaran. One question. If I wanted to return multiple objects from the array (i.e there are two entries with beef) how would I do this? I know this would have worked with .filter, but can it work with .find?

Comment: please use filter instead of find method.and also change  return statement like arrayobject.length ? arrayobject : 'a is not a meat!'

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been really helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the object with the wanted name and check if you got an object or not.

```js
function printByName(name) {
    var object = array1.find(object => object.name === name);
    if (!object) return name + " is not a meat!";
    return object;
}

let array1 = [{ no: 1, name: "beef", from: "cow", price: 5 }, { no: 2, name: "pork", from: "pig", price: 10 }];

console.log(printByName("beef"));
console.log(printByName("fish"));
```

Comment: This is very helpfull. Thank you!